# Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывались 2 функции сразу если выделено 2 флажка

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def check():
    if c1.get()==1:
        discr()
    elif c2.get()==1:
        FunCompute()



root=Tk()
c1 = IntVar(root)
c2 = IntVar(root)
c1.set(0)
c2.set(0)
che1 = Checkbutton(root,text="Discr",
variable=c1,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che2 = Checkbutton(root,text="FunCompute",
variable=c2,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
but=Button(root,text='open',command=check)
but.pack()
che1.pack()
che2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elif` в функции замените на `if` (т.е. будет 2 независимых условия `if`). Если будут включены оба чекбокса, то обе функции выполнятся, сначала одна, потом другая (надеюсь это подходит под условие "открывались 2 функции сразу").